# Run javascript after navigating to a page

Tags: javascript, dom, pug, dom-events

I have the following javascript in some `pug` file:

```
doctype html
html
    //- this is not firing for some reason
    head

        script(type="text/javascript").
          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
              console.log('ready!')
         }, false);
```

the script only runs when I refresh the page, not when I navigate to the page the script do not fire. I am looking for an event like `onNavigate`, however I do not see it in the list here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp or here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: Most likely, by the time your script is loaded and attached to the handler, `DOMContentLoaded` has already fired

Comment: my suggestion is to wrap your code in an if statement and check `document.readyState`.

Comment: @Derek `DOMContentLoaded` shouldn't fire until after all the HTML is loaded, which executes the JS.

Comment: @Derek Why would it be different when refreshing? They both load the document the same way.

Comment: @Barmar agreed, however in my personal experience, I've stumbled across the same issue and it had to do with it firing before the handler was attached and it was because of the location of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work fine(if you code is written in this way). Don't see a problem.

```
<!doctype html>
   <html>
    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
           console.log('ready!')
        }, false);
      </script>
    </body>
   </html>
```

or

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    console.log('ready!')
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should really explain why this issue is occurring

Comment: @Derek, DOMContentLoaded only fires when your HTML is loaded and ready. The above code should fire and console even if you navigate from one page to the other.

Comment: Lol, not here, in the answer. Generally, "Try this" answers should be avoided if they can be. Insight into the problem makes the person smarter.

Answer (score 2):

Ya know the body OnLoad event occurs *after* any css and js loads - including external refs.

All you really need is:

```
<body onload="do_this()">
```

and then in the script element

```
function do_this(){
//  do sh1t
}
```